# Do grad school look at every application despite cGPA? For masters in urban planning

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I attend McGill university and I have a learning disability (recorded by the school). During covid-19, adjusting was very difficult. Therefore, I do not have the best grades. However, since classes restarted in person and I received some help, I managed to pull on average a B+ and occasionally a B or A-.

I have a lot of passion for all things related to urban. To stand out despite my low grades, I did a double major (economics and urban studies), RA-ship in a related field and published some papers in undergrad journals. These are the achievements I would love to mention in my letter during application. I also fluently speak three languages and completed two internships in banking during my bachelors. However, would my average cGPA of 3.1 have me filtered? Or would the admission office still look at my recent grades and/or letter?

---

Edit: I also completed two internships in banking during my bachelors.

Comment: Please just use the "edit" button under the question to acually edit the question - do not post edits as answers. I added the info to your question.

Comment: In the US,  masters programs are typically self-paid. They vary in competitiveness and I know our medium program would not have an issue with a 3.1 GPA.